# ros_master_uri - change it and save it

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there a simple way to store change of ROS_MASTER_URI? So when ever I boot up my machine (or start node) this would always be changed to for example:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://ubuntu:11311
```

Now it changes always back to default

```
$ echo $ROS_MASTER_URI 
http://localhost:11311
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35603/ros_master_uri---change-it-and-save-it/) by [ajr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/1453/ajr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes - add a line to your ~/.bashrc  (assuming you're using bash)

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://ubuntu:11311
```

If it's in your ~/.bashrc, it'll be exported every time you open up a new terminal. If you want edits to this file to take effect in your current terminal, type:

```
source ~/.basrhc
```

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2012-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2012-06-04**:
Nitpicking: assuming you're using Bash, not Ubuntu ;) (type "echo $0" to know your shell, Bash by default under Ubuntu)

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2012-06-05**:
@Thomas - Thanks! Edited to include your correction....